# Socket.io what if there are two applications on the same server IP?

Tags: socket.io

When we connect to socket.io, we have to define the server IP, or leave it blank if the files are hosted in the same server.

Each emit we fire, will be thrown on each socket connection.

If we have two applications on the same server,
all of the emits from app1 will be emitted in app2 and vice versa.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Since it appears you may be new here, in the future, questions about code SHOULD include the relevant code in your question so we can answer more precisely about your specific situation.  For some unknown reason, people that are new here tend to think it's better to ask a "generic" question with either no code or with made up pseudo-code.  That is pretty much never the best option.  You should include the relevant portions of your actual code so we can see your exact situation and so we can recommend exact code to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon what you mean by "two applications".  If what you mean is two connections to the same socket.io server, then yes `io.emit()` is purposely designed to send to all connections to the current server.

If you have two separate socket.io servers on the same host, then those socket.io servers must be on separate ports (you can't have two actual servers on the same port) and when you `io.emit()` to one it will have nothing to do with the other because the `io` objects for the two servers will be completely different objects that are attached to completely different servers.

So, it really depends upon how you have things configured on the host.  If you show your actual server-side code for your two servers, we could answer much more specifically.

If you just have one socket.io server and you're looking for ways to send a message to a group of connected sockets, you can either use [namespaces or rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).  A namespace is something a client connects to.  A room is something a server puts a connection into with `.join()`.  You can then `.emit()` to either a namespace or a room and it will send to all sockets in that collection.

Comment: I have one server. Two different apps, as for two different projects.
I want to send emit about an update in app1. But I just do not want it to be emitted in app2. Like folders, is there an option to send the emit to folder named: "app1" in the server?

Comment: @Raz - I still don't understand.  What is an "app" in your context?  One server, two different apps does not explain it to me.  socket.io has namespaces and rooms that allow you to emit to specific groups of socket.io connections and send to only a specific group.  I can't tell if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. 
When I say different apps, I mean two different websites, with two different domains. Just another two apps.
Could you please explain more about namespaces and rooms of socketio?

Comment: @Raz - How can you have two different websites with different domains sharing the same socket.io server.  Are you pointing two separate domains at the exact same IP address and thus have just one body of code that receives requests from both domains?  How is that two apps?  Makes no sense to me.  My answer contains references to socket.io namespaces and rooms.  Beyond that, I think I'm going to stop here unless you show actual code that shows what "two apps using the same server" actually is.